# List of Json records

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a list of json records, for instance:

```
[{“age”:27,”lastname”:”Robert “,”firstName”:”Rob”,”company”:”abc”},

{“age”:27,”lastname”:”Ashok “,”firstName”:”Bob”,”company”:”def”},

{“age”:27,”lastname”:”murali“,”firstName”:”Got”,”company”,”Ghori”}]
```

Write a method which takes lastName as parameter and based on that input I need to get only that particular record out and get it displayed

Comment: Please clearly state the problem you are facing, what you have tried, and a specific question for which you are seeking help.

Comment: I tried fetching a record based on the last name but I get error like cannot be cast to JSONArray I used JSONObject and JSONArray which didn’t worked for me

Comment: Post the code and the full error here in the question. We can't help with code you don't show us.

Answer (score -2):

Your probleme is not well explained, you can try this solution (after correcting your string to be a real json content)

Using ObjectMapper you can read your string to transform it to an ArrayNode

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json= "[\n" +
                    "   {\n" +
                    "      \"age\":27,\n" +
                    "      \"lastname\":\"Robert \",\n" +
                    "      \"firstName\":\"Rob\",\n" +
                    "      \"company\":\"abc\"\n" +
                    "   },\n" +
                    "   {\n" +
                    "      \"age\":27,\n" +
                    "      \"lastname\":\"Ashok \",\n" +
                    "      \"firstName\":\"Bob\",\n" +
                    "      \"company\":\"def\"\n" +
                    "   },\n" +
                    "   {\n" +
                    "      \"age\":27,\n" +
                    "      \"lastname\":\"murali\",\n" +
                    "      \"firstName\":\"Got\",\n" +
                    "      \"company\":\"\"\n" +
                    "   }\n" +
                    "]";
    // example with murali
    getLine(json, "murali");
}

private static String getLine(String json, String lastName) throws IOException {
    ArrayNode rootNode = (ArrayNode) new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
    for(JsonNode jsonNode : rootNode) {
        ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode)jsonNode;
        String lastNameValue = node.get("lastname").textValue();
        if(lastName.equals(lastNameValue)){
            return jsonNode.toString();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

the result for this example is :

{"age":27,"lastname":"murali","firstName":"Got","company":""}